# Find all data that were created between 9 am and 4pm Rails 3.2.1 and postgreSQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, time

I have a requirement to display all data that were inserted in between 9 am and 5 pm ignoring dates.

I have tried

```
.where(created_at: Time.parse("9am")..Time.parse("5pm"))
```

**Because Time.parse results in current data and time. So this display only today's result between 9 am and 5 pm.But I need all the data that were entered in between 9am and 5pm **

---

I tried to solve using time data field in database. Database stores correctly but when we query through rails the year 01-01-2000 was appended in time.

Although it is a very simple problem, I am stuck.

### Please help me to figure out this problem.

Comment: What database server are you using? Are you OK with adding a "Time" field (24 hour, like "4" or "16")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL defines a function `EXTRACT` described here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html

You might be able to query using something like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM (modelname) WHERE EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at) > (minhour) AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at) < (maxhour);
```